# Stepping through JSON object with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON object that I need to be able to step through each object in the array. I'm currently able to show all items, but need to be able to only show the first one on load. On button click, it needs to iterate to the next object in the array, and display only the next object, so on and so forth.

As an example of this functionality: http://jsbin.com/veyegihogi/edit?html,js,output

The current setup:

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('portfolioController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.indexToShow = 0;
    $http.get("shows.json")
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.results = response.data;
      });
      $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.indexToShow = ($scope.indexToShow + 1) % $scope.results.length;
    };
});
```

Markup:

```
<div id="images" ng-repeat="items in results">
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <img src="{{items.image_url}}" alt="{{items.title}}">
      </div>
</div>
<div class="simple-button" ng-click="change()">click me!</div>
```

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title 1",
    "count": 14,
    "image_url": "images/image.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title 2",
    "count": 10,
    "image_url": "images/image2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "title 3",
    "count": 8,
    "image_url": "images/image3.jpg"
  }
]
```

Comment: I do not see an `ng-click` in your markup? Also `product_image_url` does not match it's objects `image_url` Furthermore... I see no reason to have `$scope.change` inside your `$http.get()`

Comment: also is the ng-repeat a requirement if it really is just suppose to show the next one on click?

Comment: `src="{{items[indexToShow].product_image_url}}"` and remove ng-repeat. It seems obvious! what is it that is confusing to you?

Comment: No sure what your asking? you want to step through each key of the object in the array? or are you int interested in 1 value of the object? http://jsbin.com/voqoqefada/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You have all the code ready for this ;)

You just want this view part instead of your ng-repeat

```
<div id="images">
      <img src="{{results[indexToShow].image_url}}" alt="{{results[indexToShow].title}}">
</div>
<div class="simple-button" ng-click="change()">click me!</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! Part of the issue, which I forgot to add to the original question, was adding a button to display for each of the objects in the array, below the main image area, where each has the id of the image it should show on click.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want ?

Comment: So there should be buttons below the currently displayed item, for each of the available objects in the json file. When you click on one, it'll show the corresponding content from that id. So, instead of a single "next" button, it'll be a button for each available item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your jsbin...

```
<div id="images" ng-repeat="item in results track by $index" ng-show="$index == indexToShow">
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <img src="{{item.image_url}}" alt="{{item.title}}">
      </div>
</div>
<div class="simple-button" ng-click="change()">click me!</div>
```

Comment: Just remove the ng-repeat ... that make no sense.

Comment: I know, but I wasn't sure if the repeater was some weird requirement  (see my comments above) so I provided a solution with the repeater in the same way as the referenced jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

Can set a scope variable for `selectedItem` and do the indexing in controller

```
$scope.results = response.data;
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.results[0];

$scope.change = function(){
    var currIdx = $scope.results.indexOf($scope.selectedItem),
        nextIdx = currIdx+1 <= $scope.results.length-1 ? currIdx+1 : 0;

    $scope.selectedItem=$scope.results[nextIdx ];
};
```

View

```
<img src="{{selectedItem.product_image_url}}"...>
```

To create pager buttons set selected item in `ng-click` or pass `item` to a function and set it in controller:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in results" 
      ng-class="{active: item == selectedItem}}" 
      ng-click="selectedItem = item">{{$index+1}}</span>
```